# Calculate the sum of hours of an employee between a specific date range

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to calculate the amount of hours per employee of its absence during a date range (START_DATE_ABSENCE & END_DATE_ABSENCE). What makes it difficult is that this employee may also have working hours on Saturday or Sunday or working less than 40 hours.
I do not know how to do this.

The query below results in this:
[Result of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsRB5.png)

The days is the working scheme of an employee. This scheme is different for every employee. It is possible that this employee works on Saturday f.e.

```
SELECT EMP_A.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, 
        EMP_P.START_DATE AS START_DATE_ABSENCE, 
        EMP_P.END_DATE AS END_DATE_ABSENCE,
        EMP_A.MONDAY,
        EMP_A.TUESDAY,
        EMP_A.WEDNESDAY,
        EMP_A.THURSDAY,
        EMP_A.FRIDAY,
        EMP_A.SATURDAY,
        EMP_A.SUNDAY
FROM XXAS.XXAS_FHT_EMPLOYEES_ALL_MV EMP_A
JOIN XXAS.XXAS_FHT_EMP_PERIODS_R EMP_P
ON EMP_P.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = EMP_A.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
WHERE EMP_A.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = '1000599'
AND EMP_P.START_DATE >= SYSDATE
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

I have tried to count the number of Mondays (and all the other days) present in the date range but that does not seem like a solid solution and I came across perfomance issues:

```
WITH mondays AS (
  SELECT EMP_P.START_DATE + LEVEL - 1 AS M
  FROM XXAS.XXAS_FHT_EMP_PERIODS_R EMP_P
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= EMP_P.END_DATE - EMP_P.START_DATE + 1
)
SELECT count(*) NR_OF_MONDAYS
FROM MONDAYS
WHERE (TO_CHAR(M, 'D') = '2')
AND ROWNUM < 5
;
```

Comment: Please provide your table structure, sample data and expected results ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `CROSS APPLY` and a hierarchical query to generate rows for each date in the absence range and correlate that to the days of the week and the expected hours:

```sql
SELECT EMP_A.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, 
       EMP_P.START_DATE AS START_DATE_ABSENCE, 
       EMP_P.END_DATE AS END_DATE_ABSENCE,
       EMP_A.MONDAY,
       EMP_A.TUESDAY,
       EMP_A.WEDNESDAY,
       EMP_A.THURSDAY,
       EMP_A.FRIDAY,
       EMP_A.SATURDAY,
       EMP_A.SUNDAY,
       total_absence
FROM   XXAS.XXAS_FHT_EMPLOYEES_ALL_MV EMP_A
       JOIN XXAS.XXAS_FHT_EMP_PERIODS_R EMP_P
       ON EMP_P.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = EMP_A.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
       CROSS APPLY(
         SELECT SUM(
                  CASE TRUNC(EMP_P.START_DATE + LEVEL - 1)
                       - TRUNC(EMP_P.START_DATE + LEVEL - 1, 'IW')
                  WHEN 0 THEN EMP_A.MONDAY
                  WHEN 1 THEN EMP_A.TUESDAY
                  WHEN 2 THEN EMP_A.WEDNESDAY
                  WHEN 3 THEN EMP_A.THURSDAY
                  WHEN 4 THEN EMP_A.FRIDAY
                  WHEN 5 THEN EMP_A.SATURDAY
                  WHEN 6 THEN EMP_A.SUNDAY
                  END
                ) AS total_absence
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY EMP_P.START_DATE + LEVEL - 1 <= EMP_P.END_DATE
       )
WHERE  EMP_A.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = '1000599'
AND    EMP_P.START_DATE >= SYSDATE
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE XXAS.XXAS_FHT_EMPLOYEES_ALL_MV (
  employee_number, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday) AS
SELECT '1000599', 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0 FROM DUAL

CREATE TABLE XXAS.XXAS_FHT_EMP_PERIODS_R (
  employee_number, start_date, end_date) AS
SELECT '1000599', DATE '2023-04-26', DATE '2023-05-03' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| EMPLOYEE_NUMBER | START_DATE_ABSENCE | END_DATE_ABSENCE | MONDAY | TUESDAY | WEDNESDAY | THURSDAY | FRIDAY | SATURDAY | SUNDAY | TOTAL_ABSENCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000599 | 2023-04-26 00:00:00 | 2023-05-03 00:00:00 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 48 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/anJ0QP2k)